# How to write a Build.scala to change a SettingKey priviously assigned in build.sbt

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have a `build.sbt`:

```
name := "name"
```

And a `project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
object MyBuild extends Build {
  val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
  override def settings = super.settings :+ (
    Keys.name in root ~= { oldName => oldName + "-in-scala" }
  )
}
```

I want a transformer in `project/Build.scala`, which can changes `name` to `name-in-scala`. But it does not work.

How can I write a transformer in `Build.scala`?

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Maybe there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.
The page 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#relating-build-sbt-to-build-scala states about SBT 0.12.1:

> The setting in build.sbt should "win" over the one in Build.scala.

and

> The settings in .sbt files are appended to the settings in .scala files.